# Add Invisible reCAPTCHA in to an existing contact form

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

Good Day!

To add security feature i want to add Invisible reCAPTCHA to my existing forms and in this case the contact form.

Please see the existing code:

```html
<script>
var blogId = '12345678901';
var contactFormMessageSendingMsg ='Sending...';
var contactFormMessageSentMsg = 'Your message has been sent.';
var contactFormMessageNotSentMsg = 'Message could not be sent. Please try again later.';
var contactFormEmptyMessageMsg ='Message field cannot be empty.';
var contactFormInvalidEmailMsg = 'A valid email is required.'

var widgetLoaded=false;
function sendEmailMsg() {
if(widgetLoaded== false) {
_WidgetManager._RegisterWidget('_ContactFormView', new _WidgetInfo('ContactForm1', 'sidebar', null, document.getElementById('ContactForm1'), {'contactFormMessageSendingMsg': contactFormMessageSendingMsg , 'contactFormMessageSentMsg': contactFormMessageSentMsg , 'contactFormMessageNotSentMsg': contactFormMessageNotSentMsg , 'contactFormInvalidEmailMsg': contactFormInvalidEmailMsg , 'contactFormEmptyMessageMsg': contactFormEmptyMessageMsg , 'title': 'Contact Form', 'blogId': blogId, 'contactFormNameMsg': 'Name', 'contactFormEmailMsg': 'Email', 'contactFormMessageMsg': 'Message', 'contactFormSendMsg': 'Send', 'submitUrl': 'https://www.blogger.com/contact-form.do'}, 'displayModeFull'));
widgetLoaded=true;
document.getElementById('ContactForm1_contact-form-submit').click();
}
return true;
}
</script>
<form name='contact-form'>
<div>Your Name : </div>
<input class='contact-form-name' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-name' name='name' size='30' type='text' value=''/>
<div>Your Email: <em>(required)</em></div>
<input class='contact-form-email' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-email' name='email' size='30' type='text' value=''/>
<div>Your Message: <em>(required)</em></div>
<textarea class='contact-form-email-message' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message' name='email-message' rows='5'></textarea>
<p></p>

<input class='contact-form-button contact-form-button-submit' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-submit' type='button' value='Send' onclick="sendEmailMsg()"/>


<div style='text-align: center; max-width: 450px; width: 100%'>
<p class='contact-form-error-message' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-error-message'></p>
<p class='contact-form-success-message' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-success-message'></p>
</div>
</form>
```

i tried to insert the code from the googlw re captcha site but it wont work:

```html
<button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my site key" data-callback='sendEmailMsg()'>Submit</button>
```

do i need to just indicate the function on callback or do i need to configure the class and id??

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call `sendEmailMsg()` directly. As stated in [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#auto_render), you have to call your function in the callback:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<script>
  function onSubmit(token) {
    sendEmailMsg();
  }
</script>
```

Call onSubmit function, remove your click event and put class and data required by Google in your existing submit button:

```
<input class='g-recaptcha contact-form-button contact-form-button-submit' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-submit' type='button' value='Send' data-sitekey='your site key' data-callback='onSubmit()'/>
```

And here is your full code:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<script>
  function onSubmit(token) {
    sendEmailMsg();
  }
</script>
<script>
  var blogId = '12345678901';
  var contactFormMessageSendingMsg = 'Sending...';
  var contactFormMessageSentMsg = 'Your message has been sent.';
  var contactFormMessageNotSentMsg = 'Message could not be sent. Please try again later.';
  var contactFormEmptyMessageMsg = 'Message field cannot be empty.';
  var contactFormInvalidEmailMsg = 'A valid email is required.'

  var widgetLoaded = false;

  function sendEmailMsg() {
    if (widgetLoaded == false) {
      _WidgetManager._RegisterWidget('_ContactFormView', new _WidgetInfo('ContactForm1', 'sidebar', null, document.getElementById('ContactForm1'), {
        'contactFormMessageSendingMsg': contactFormMessageSendingMsg,
        'contactFormMessageSentMsg': contactFormMessageSentMsg,
        'contactFormMessageNotSentMsg': contactFormMessageNotSentMsg,
        'contactFormInvalidEmailMsg': contactFormInvalidEmailMsg,
        'contactFormEmptyMessageMsg': contactFormEmptyMessageMsg,
        'title': 'Contact Form',
        'blogId': blogId,
        'contactFormNameMsg': 'Name',
        'contactFormEmailMsg': 'Email',
        'contactFormMessageMsg': 'Message',
        'contactFormSendMsg': 'Send',
        'submitUrl': 'https://www.blogger.com/contact-form.do'
      }, 'displayModeFull'));
      widgetLoaded = true;
      document.getElementById('ContactForm1_contact-form-submit').click();
    }
    return true;
  }
</script>
<form name='contact-form'>
    <div>Your Name :</div>
    <input class='contact-form-name' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-name' name='name' size='30' type='text' value='' />
    <div>Your Email: <em>(required)</em></div>
    <input class='contact-form-email' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-email' name='email' size='30' type='text' value='' />
    <div>Your Message: <em>(required)</em></div>
    <textarea class='contact-form-email-message' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message' name='email-message' rows='5'></textarea>
    <p></p>

    <input class='g-recaptcha contact-form-button contact-form-button-submit' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-submit' type='button' value='Send' data-sitekey='your site key' data-callback='onSubmit()'/>


    <div style='text-align: center; max-width: 450px; width: 100%'>
        <p class='contact-form-error-message' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-error-message'></p>
        <p class='contact-form-success-message' id='ContactForm1_contact-form-success-message'></p>
    </div>
</form>
```